# How do I make the background color take the full height of the screen/page?

Tags: html, css

As you can see, the background color of `<aside>` has not taken the full height of the page (empty white space above the nav bar), How do I fix this, so it takes the full height of the screen?

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

li {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<aside>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul class="center">
          <a>
            <li>Home</li>
          </a>
          <a>
            <li>Projects</li>
          </a>
          <a>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the `position` of the container to `fixed` and thereafter make its `height` to `100%` and set `top` to `0`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 7rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

li {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<aside>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul class="center">
          <a>
            <li>Home</li>
          </a>
          <a>
            <li>Projects</li>
          </a>
          <a>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background-color to the body tag, or wrap the whole thing in a div, and set the background color on the div.